# How to find all the REST APIs exposed by a Web Service?

Tags: web-services, rest

If I just have an accessible end point of an Web Service, is there a way to find out all the APIs exposed by that?

Comment: Is that a wcf rest or a webapi?

Answer (score -1):

Considering the api to be WCF Rest, If help is enabled, you can see all the operations exposed by the endpoint by browsing to endpoint/help.

More here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442(v=vs.110).aspx